# Obtengo nulo cuando intento acceder a auth()->user() en laravel blade cuando inicio sesión con ajax

Tags: laravel, ajax, login, auth

Estoy desarrollando un sistema en Laravel 8.x, así que estoy haciendo un inicio de sesión, todo va bien, pero cuando uso auth()->user() en la plantilla blade me arroja nulo, he mirado en la documentación, pero no puedo encontrar una solución

**Funcion Login en JavaScript**

```
const login = () =>{

   if(validarLogin()){ 
    let url = document.location.origin+'/api/login'
    let method = 'POST'
    
    var form_data = new FormData()
    form_data.append('email', $('#correo').val().trim())
    form_data.append('password', $('#contrasena').val().trim())
    form_data.append('personal_code', $('#codigo').val().trim())
    enviarPeticion(url, method, form_data, 'continuarLogin')

}   }
```

**Login Controller Laravel**

```
public function login(Request $request){

    $fields = $request->validate([
        'email' => 'required|string|email',
        'password' => 'required|string',
        'personal_code' => 'required|string'
    ]);

    $user = User::where('email', $fields['email'])
    ->where('personal_code', $fields['personal_code'])->first();

    if(!$user || !Hash::check($fields['password'], $user->password)){
        
        return Util::setResponseJson(401,'Credenciales inválidas, revise que el correo, contraseña o que el código sea el correcto.');

    }else if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $fields['email'], 'password' => $fields['password'], 'status' => 1])) {
            return Util::setResponseJson(200, auth()->user(), "");
    }       
}
```

**Respuesta de backend en el Ajax success**

Cuando imprimo la respuesta en el front-end con una consola, obtengo los datos del usuario que inició sesión

```
{"status":200,"message":{"id":17,"name":"User Admin","email":"mail@mail.edu.co","email_verified_at":null,"created_at":"2022-04-08T00:14:17.000000Z","updated_at":"2022-04-13T19:13:23.000000Z","id_rol":2,"status":1,"ind_blocked":null,"time_blocked":null,"ind_banned":null,"failed_login_attempts":2,"blocked_date":null,"banned_date":null,"personal_code":"OIBA1696"},"token":"147|tXUb21MuW4hhpAgyhV38TJSKBTBeS6DQdO7Sx4xY"}
```

Pero cuando imprimo el usuario que ha iniciado sesión en la plantilla blade después de iniciar sesión, arroja un valor nulo

```
 <div class="card-body">       
    {{var_dump(auth()->user())}}
 </div>
```

Comment: Recuerda que puedes [edit] :)

Comment: La ruta o controlador que sirve esa vista está bajo el middleware `auth`?

Comment: No amigo, no está bajo middleware aún, ¿Será por eso?.

Comment: Si le agrego el middleware auth siempre me redirecciona a la vista login.

Comment: Que sistema de autenticación estás usando?

Comment: el sistema Auth